# Getting notification badge number based on delivered notification swift

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I have an application which receives Push Notification and these notifications are delivered properly to the device. However when these notifications are delivered badge does not count. I have read online that one sends badge number with the payload which I understand but does not work for my case. Notifications are delivered based on different instances and I want to be a able to increase the badge number based on the available notifications the user has not opened his device to view.

With payload, there is no way to know if a user viewed the notification already and zero it. I am trying to avoid setting a badge in the payload to maybe 7 whereas the unopened notification on the device is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since push notification are handled by iOS and not by ios app you can't change the application badge on receiving a push notification.

Though you can send the badge number in the payload of the push notification as you already send, so you have to do the calculation on server side.

Go through [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1) and especially the [The Notification Payload](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH17-SW1).